# How to allow Location and Notifications in Chrome incognito mode in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to allow location and notifications on Chrome in incognito mode using `Selenium`.

Here is my code:

```py
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
option = Options()

option.add_argument("--incognito")
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications":1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1,
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option, executable_path="path/to/executable")
```

This code works (Notifications and Location are enabled) if `option.add_argument("--incognito")` isn't included (the browser is opened in normal mode). Why is this happening and how can I enable these along with incognito mode?

Note: You can check if the location is enabled by open a website that requests your location.

Browser's view in incognito:
[image]

Comment: Are you getting an error of some sort?

Comment: No. No error. Just the browser isn't allowed to use location or notifications when it is started with the `--incognito` mode (although it should). Else (without incognito) it does get these permissions...

Comment: https://mylocation.org shows my location in incognito mode. So, what website are you querying with your code?

Comment: try, which website wants to tracks your location

Comment: While I was testing the code I used google maps...

Comment: @Asil which website are you trying to access using Selenium?

Comment: same google maps. If you can't find it try to go X to Y and you can find a button about location right bottom side it's title is 'send your location'.

Comment: @AsilAçku Can you please share the section of code that you use to open google maps?  I used this driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps/') and it shows my approximate location when Chrome opens in incognito mode.

Comment: dude, maps always working in normal mode incognito mode but there is a one trick so that's " I want to share my live location" you can try it like;
open google maps then try go to Paris to London and you will see a button bottom-left side share live location or share location something liek that I use my own language so it could be a bit different when you click it the navigator gives an error please share your location I want to allow it's with programming side but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asil Açku based on your question and your comments, I don't have a firm handled on what you are trying to accomplish.

The code below opens a Chrome browser in incognito mode using *Selenium.*  The website being accessed is Google Maps with an exact geolocation. Once the page loads Google automatically obtains my current location. It does this with no browser notifications.

If this isn't what you need please provide more details.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium import webdriver

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

prefs = {
    'profile.default_content_setting_values':
    {
        'notifications': 1,
        'geolocation': 1
    },

    'profile.managed_default_content_settings':
    {
        'geolocation': 1
    },
}

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
capabilities.update(chrome_options.to_capabilities())

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

url='https://www.google.com/maps/@48.1152117,-1.6634771,12.79z/data=!5m1!1e1'
driver.get(url)

# time used only for testing
time.sleep(10)
```

You mentioned something about "**sharing your live location**" in Google Maps.  Since you want to open Chrome in incognito mode, this capability isn't available. In this cloaked mode your location history or shared location information will not be updated with anyone that you are are sharing this information with.

**Google Maps Location Sharing in Chrome**
[image]

**Google Maps Location Sharing in incognito mode**
[image]

Comment: """Since you want to open Chrome in incognito mode, this capability isn't available. In this cloaked mode your location history or shared location information will not be updated with anyone that you are are sharing this information with. """ I want to do it,

Please try;
Open maps.google.com then try to go Poland to Austria and you'll see the bottom side 5 buttons, like Street View,Zoom in, Zoom out, Share Location-- when you click the share location, it gives you alert google.com wants to know your location -- Accept, Reject 

I don't want to see this alert, I want to set it enabled

Comment: @AsilAçku In order for me to share my location via maps.google.com, I have to enable that service on my mobile device.  When not using incognito mode I can share my location, but in incognito mode I cannot share my service even when I login my Gmail account.

Comment: @AsilAçku please post and image to your question so I can see your browser view in incognito mode.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kXw0Qg7 take a look please I tried to add post but it told that queqe is full

Comment: @AsilAçku Based on your image - you are clicking on "konumunu göster," which launches a notification window - "www.google.com Şunu yapmak istiyor konumunuz bilme."  When I run my code, I don't have to click the "konumunu göster" button or the button in the notification window.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it was my bad, I tried but I coded wrong maybe.. again Sorry, Thank you for your interest.

Comment: @AsilAçku You're welcome.  I was happy to help you.  Good luck with your coding.